# Linux Multimedia Studio Sound Font note fade away

Tags: composition, software, sound

I am currently trying out some sound-fonts I just downloaded, in [Linux Multimedia Studio (LMMS)](http://lmms.sourceforge.net). All is going well, besides the fact that I haven't, even after a Google search, found out how to make a soundfont's note fade out or in. At the suggestion of one YouTube video, I tried using the Automation editor, yet, though it affected the default preset and other such types of instruments, it had no effect whatsoever on the soundfont (.sf2) files I am using.

I am still inclined to think that the automation editor is what will accomplish this in the end, yet I need some guidance. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: You used an obscure acronym that you did not define in context, so after I figured out what LMMS is, I modified your question.

Comment: Thank you! I should have used the full name, I guess that I was just to lazy to type it out. :)

Comment: Perhaps I should add that I am on a Windows XP (yeah, yeah, I know) with the latest version of LMMS.

Answer (score 1):

Sf2 files are harder to modify than built-in instruments. The best bet is to try adjusting the volume's attack level or decay on the instrument. also you can add reverb as an effect. Personally I prefer free VST plugins. They sound more realistic. look up synths like synth1, oatmeal, and dsk music's assortment if you prefer more natural sounds. You can get even nicer ones if you're willing to pay for them, but judging by the fact you're using LMMS in the first place I assume that's not an option.

Comment: :) Yes, I am going with free. I will check out those VST plugins and see what I get with playing around with the SF2s...